# Toshiba Satellite M50D-A-10Z boot failure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios, toshiba-laptop

So I have a problem with booting up on my Toshiba Satellite. 
I've been trying to install Wine for Ubuntu and in the middle of the process I've encountered an error message in my terminal saying that something malfunctioned in /etc/... directory ( I can't remember what exactly). After that I've tried several more commands but the same message would appear again. I restarted the laptop thinking that it would help but it couldn't pass the "welcoming screen" (black screen with Toshiba logo).
I have tried entering BIOS, holding 0 while turning on the laptop and few other methods that were recommended on some other forums but nothing worked.
Does anyone have any idea what could be going on? Is it some weird software failure or hardware problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tried entering BIOS, holding 0
```

To enter the BIOS on a Toshiba laptop, instead of holding the "0" key, **press the F2 key quietly**.

I insist on the **quietly**, that is about half a second, as I observed on a Toshiba Satellite C670-17Q, that pressing F2 too quickly (even repeatedly) or holding it down does not permit entering the BIOS.